# Django + Postgres: Trying dump and restore database, but are seeing ERROR: relation "*_id_seq" does not exist for all sequence tables

Tags: django, postgresql

I am trying to move a database from a virtual machine (docker-machine) over to a database server on azure. I am first using the following command to dump the database to a local file:

`pg_dump -h <virtual-machine-ip> -U <username> postgres > dump.sql`

Then I try to restore it on the new server:

`psql -h <database-server-ip> -U <username> -d <new_database_name> -f dump.sql`

Which produces a lot of errors (example below):

```
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
COMMENT
CREATE EXTENSION
COMMENT
SET
SET
SET
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
psql:dump.sql:66: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 2:     AS integer
            ^
psql:dump.sql:69: ERROR:  relation "auth_group_id_seq" does not exist
psql:dump.sql:75: ERROR:  relation "auth_group_id_seq" does not exist
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
psql:dump.sql:101: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 2:     AS integer
            ^
psql:dump.sql:104: ERROR:  relation "auth_group_permissions_id_seq" does not exist
psql:dump.sql:110: ERROR:  relation "auth_group_permissions_id_seq" does not exist
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
psql:dump.sql:137: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 2:     AS integer
            ^
psql:dump.sql:140: ERROR:  relation "auth_permission_id_seq" does not exist
psql:dump.sql:146: ERROR:  relation "auth_permission_id_seq" does not exist
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
psql:dump.sql:175: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 2:     AS integer
            ^
psql:dump.sql:178: ERROR:  relation "clients_client_id_seq" does not exist
psql:dump.sql:184: ERROR:  relation "clients_client_id_seq" does not exist
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
psql:dump.sql:214: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 2:     AS integer
```

I have tried reading the docs on pg_dump, but whatever I do, I get the same result...

Any idea of what is happening here? Have I missed some options that should have been included in the dump command?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Two questions. (1) What is the first error you get and (2) does this work on a local version of the database?

Comment: (1) I updated the question with the beginning of the output, (2) what do you mean?

Comment: You have a syntax error just before the error referencing the sequence. There may be some difference between your docker version of PostgreSQL and the version on Azure. It may be that the docker version is newer. The obvious next step is to confirm you can dump and restore locally. If that works then you need to figure out what is on or near line 66 in the dump file that Azure's installation doesn't like.

Comment: I see. I will try to dump and restore locally to see if it works

Comment: It is the following statement that causes the error:

`CREATE SEQUENCE auth_group_id_seq AS integer START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NO MINVALUE NO MAXVALUE CACHE 1;`

Comment: I see that azure only supports postgres 9.x, and it looks like AS data_type is new as of 10.x, so you are completly correct

Comment: im having the same error .. did someone solve this?
Looking at the docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html the syntax is fine but even entering the bare minimum i also get a syntax error while creating the sequences. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Valdemar stated, the AS integer was introduced in 10.x, and is not backwards-compatible. If you are able to regenerate the dump through the command-line interface (pg_dump), here are the steps I would advise :

- Dump the database in plain-text format using the -Fp (or --format=plain)
- Edit the generated file to get rid of the AS integer statements
- Import the altered file in your destination database

TL;DR

```
pg_dump -h <virtual-machine-ip> -U <username> -Fp postgres > dump.sql
sed 's/AS integer//' dump.sql > altered_dump.sql
psql -h <database-server-ip> -U <username> -d <new_database_name> -f altered_dump.sql
```